# Web application - Browser/Computer identification

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, browser

We have a business web application where users can login from various places. Tablets, Office PCs and some special stationary workplaces.

If a user logs in from those special stationary terminals, additional functionality is available.

How can we securely detect if the user is using one of those terminals?

**IP-Adresses** are not possible since the networks are segmented and we do not control the router (we cannot ensure that X-Forwarded-For is present).

We thought about **Client Certificates** which would require administration overhead (renew every now and then). Also, my research shows, that certificates may not be passed through all proxys.

We considered tokens in **local storage** or stored as **cookies** as unsafe as the workers can just copy them and use them in their own browser. Also a user deleting the browser cache would cause additional work for some admin.

Are there any other options? We have full control over those terminals.

Comment: What makes those stationary terminals special?

Comment: One of them has a barcode printer next to the terminal. So if you use the terminal you get a "Print-Barcode" button exclusively for that particular terminal.